# PHP: array matching issue

Tags: php, arrays

i have array1 with following content

```
array(
'banana',
'apple',
'orange');
```

and i have a different associative array2 with content and prices of items

```
array('banana'  => '1.45',
'apple'   => '2.99',
'carrot'  => '1.99',
'orange'  => '0.99',
'papaya'  => '2.99');
```

how do i generate a final array, that combines the two, with their common parts, that i get **this final result**:

```
   array('banana'  => '1.45',
  'apple'   => '2.99',
  'orange'  => '0.99');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$fruitNames = array(
'banana',
'apple',
'orange');

$fruitValues = array('banana'  => '1.45',
  'apple'   => '2.99',
  'orange'  => '0.99');



$finalArray = array();

foreach($fruitNames as $value)
{
    $finalArray[$value] = $fruitValues[$value];
}
```

`$finalArray` will have the expected value.

Comment: this worked fine for me, i will implement it in my rather more complex code, and keep you updated ;) thanks for now.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) here.

```
$intersection = array_intersect_key($second, array_flip($first));
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/e6OrwJ).

Comment: thanks, this is what i get trying your code= Array
(
    [banana] => 0
    [apple] => 1
    [orange] => 2
)  which is not my goal here.

Comment: Check the CodePad. Make sure you have the arguments in the right order (the array of items *needs* to go second).

Comment: @Confidence, this should give the correct results, have you checked alex's Codepad link to see it in action?

Answer (score 0):

use `array_key_exists` to loop thru and make new array